# adjust output in "confirmation" in automater/applescript

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator

I am trying to build an automator application that runs an apple script which references to `rsync -a --progress --stats --human-readable` which allows you to transfer files and see the speed at which they transfer. I already have that made.

But when I use the **ask for confirmation** action in Automator to show the terminals response it has a bunch of extra information which makes it messy. I was just wondering if anyone knew how I could tell automator which keywords to keep and which keywords to leave out.

Images : 
[pictures of automator and apple script code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi6gs.jpg)

Comment: +1 for a good question that includes relevant, helpful information and screenshots.  Thanks.  Hopefully, someone can help.

Comment: I suggest to use Automator action "do shell" with a 'grep' function to restrict lines/words to be display.

Comment: @pbell I've never used the grep function.. could you explain a little please! Thanks!

Comment: Grep is a unix generic function which can select lines (or part of lines) which contain specific pattern. grep can search from files, text. the pattern could just be a value or some thing more complex. This command is so powerful that I can't give all details here. You can use man pages in Terminal. In your cases, check, in the output of rsync command the keyword(s) which tells you it is OK or not. Then use something like 'rsync -a..your parameters.. | grep keyword. If output is empty, then no keyword found, if not, output only contains the line with keyword